# Expose Travis CI Localhost to public

Tags: travis-ci

My travis container opens up some html pages on localhost:8080. I'd like these to be accessible to the public while the container is running.

How do I enable this and how do I find out the public IP address for each instance. Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Used ngrok.io for an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

exposing containers to outside world in general requires you to first establish a connection from inside the container to the gateway proxy.

there are multiple solutions available: ngrok (does not provide authentication though), [cloudflared](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/) argo tunnel and [gw.run](https://gw.run) both provide tunnel + authentication/authorization